# How to print and email PDF from any OS X application on PDF letterhead?

Tags: macos, mail.app, pdf, printing

On the Windows PC there is a nice [eDocPrinter PDF](http://www.iteksoft.com/modules.php?op=modload&name=Sections&file=index&req=viewarticle&artid=1&page=1) printer driver from [Iteksoft](http://www.iteksoft.com/) that prints from any Windows application to a PDF file overlayed with a PDF of the corporate letterhead and even attaches the result to a new mail message in the default mail client.

Regression

- The Automator.app in 10.8.5 doesn't seem to overlay PDF files, Automater.app only overlays image file formats.
- There is a [PDF printer driver project at sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfwriterformac/files/1.2.1/) which doesn't overlay and doesn't e-mail.
- Then there is the [PDF Letterhead app](http://www.lingewoud.com/sending-pdfs-with-your-own-letterhead/), which isn't a printer driver, loses it's settings on every quit and requires the creation of an intermediate temporary PDF file because this isn't a printer driver.

Who can give a hint how to create an new mail message having a PDF document attached that is overlayed with a PDF letterhead using the Mac OS X print dialog?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of PDF Letterhead in App Store keeps its settings. You can also choose "Open in PDF Letterhead" from the Print Menu. This saves you from creating a temporary PDF file.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pdf-letterhead/id976548033?mt=12

Comment: I've tried the new version that mipmip mentioned and it's working like a charm. Just what I was looking for! Cheers!